# redux state of application dissapears temporarily when called on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to call the current state of my application in the redux reducer. In the first case, I fire my action off with this code–

```
store.dispatch(addNotificationID(item, 'start', notificationID));
console.log(item.id, 'start', notificationID);
console.log(store.getState().StorageReducer.IDs); //shows accurate state
```

This successfully fires the first case of my redux reducer and then the console log of `console.log(store.getState().StorageReducer.IDs)` shows the newly added ID in the state. Then, I have the second case that I am going to eventually use to remove the ID object from the state. If I reload the application and then this action fires of type `CANCEL_NOTIFICATION` it will log the correct store. But if I fire that action in the same session that an ID was added, that will not log to the store.

here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  IDs: []
};

const storage = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        IDs:
        [
          ...state.IDs,
          {
            itemID: action.item.id,
            reminderType: action.reminderType,
            notificationID: action.notificationID
          }
        ]
      };
    case CANCEL_NOTIFICATION:
      console.log(state.IDs);
      return { ...state };
```

For example, say IDs was this when the application booted up:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "itemID": "_UE9dINF",
    "notificationID": "F7AFB9F9-45C3-4A90-AD70-1A2334CE282A",
    "reminderType": "start",
  },
]
```

Then my addNotifications action fires. During that session when the `console.log(store.getState().StorageReducer.IDs)` gets called it would look like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "itemID": "_UE9dINF",
    "notificationID": "F7AFB9F9-45C3-4A90-AD70-1A2334CE282A",
    "reminderType": "start",
  },
  Object { //this is the new object that was just added to state
    "itemID": "z4ACCSZR",
    "notificationID": "3850E623-CFA7-483C-BF22-DB07C746CE37",
    "reminderType": "start",
  },
]
```

If I reload the session and then fire the cancelNotification action the reducer case will also log that ouptut. However, if I run that action in the same session I fired the addNotifications action, instead of looking like above it will only look like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "itemID": "_UE9dINF",
    "notificationID": "F7AFB9F9-45C3-4A90-AD70-1A2334CE282A",
    "reminderType": "start",
  },
]
```

Then if I reload the session it will have the two objects as it is supposed to. I really don't understand why or how this is possible. I am using redux-persist and think the bug may be coming somewhere from that.

My redux store:

```
const todoPersistConfig = {
  key: 'TodoReducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['todos'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const storageConfig = {
  key: 'StorageReducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['IDs'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const remindersPersistConfig = {
  key: 'remindersreducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['notificationIDs'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  ModalReducer,
  RemindersReducer: persistReducer(remindersPersistConfig, RemindersReducer),
  StorageReducer: persistReducer(storageConfig, StorageReducer),
  TodoReducer: persistReducer(todoPersistConfig, TodoReducer),
  AuthReducer
});

export default function storeConfiguration() {
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    )
  );

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
}
```

There are no problems with the todo reducer, but I recreated an extra reminders reducer to duplicate and see if the issue persisted and it had the same results.